# Is it safe to query Core Data database via sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Can sqlite API be used to access the database that core data is using?
The data that I'd be querying isn't being updated, its relatively static. But I need to use joins and can't do that with Core Data.

Is it safe or are there issues doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only do this for testing outside of the application. You never know when the schema will change which could break your app.

Comment: Meaning that Core Data could change the sqlite schema with different releases of Core Data even if the core data data model doesn't change?

Comment: Apple said something to that effect in a WWDC video, but I forget which one, sorry.